# HTMLCollection change event with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, cross-browser, dom-events

If I'm assuming correctly, an HTMLCollection is dynamic.

In which changes automatically, as items, are added or removed from the document.

Is there a way to detect a change in the size of an HTMLCollection using an event handler? Besides using a timer to constantly poll the collection of course.

Comment: What browsers do you need to support?

Comment: I don't think there's such an event, but MutationObserver might be helpful, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: @Andrew Just what I had in mind as well. The problem is that it doesn't work in IE

Comment: Cross browser. Naturally. And unfortunately lol.

Comment: I guess with all my assuming I should have assumed that if there were such an event, mutation observers would be common practice and widely adopted by now.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect changes in the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom)

Answer (score 2):

Just to avoid confusion, **dynamic** means that something is modified during the runtime. HTMLCollection is **live**, which means it is dynamic plus it can be changed not just by the client script, but also by browser algorithms as declared [here](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-live-range). These algorithms can be intercepted by [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) (which is [cross-browser](https://caniuse.com/mutationobserver) today) explained by the test code below:

```js
function addItem() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = "item";
    list.appendChild(li);
}

var data = list.children;

function watch(data) {
    console.log(data);
}

var observer = new MutationObserver(watch);
observer.observe(list, {childList: true});
```

```html
<ul id="list"></ul>
<button onclick="addItem()">Add item</button>
<button onclick="console.log(data.length)">Test</button>
```

Here the `data` is the live HTMLCollection created during the load phase (before DOMContentLoaded fires), but modified by the browser algorithms anytime the *Add Item* button is pressed (it can be verified by *Test* button). The algorithms are intercepted by `observer` object which calls the `watch` callback with [MutationRecord](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord) as its argument. This can be expensive, so the [options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe) need to be set carefully and the observer should be disconnected when not needed.