# What is the best way to handle events on dynamically generated input fields

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers, htmlcollection

I'm looking for the simplest way to handle different events on dynamically generated input fields.

Using MutationObserver looks complicated because requires processing each MutationRecord from the list, additional search for input fields and adding or removing listener.

Is there an alternative to MutationObserver like some hack with HTMLCollection:

```
const inputsHTMLCollection = document.getElementsByTagName('inputs');
// some way for detecting inputsHTMLCollection changing
```

UPD

I am looking for alternative solutions in pure JS, without using any libraries.

```js
// emulate code on the page
addinput.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const i = document.createElement('input');
    i.type = "text";
    inputs.append(i);
});

const log = (e) => {
  const event = document.createElement('div');
  event.innerText = `${e.type}: on ${e.target.tagName}`;
  events.prepend(event);
};


const inputsHTMLCollection = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (let i of inputsHTMLCollection) {
  i.addEventListener('focus', log);
};

// After addinput click - the inputsHTMLCollection length will be changed
// some code, for detect length change here
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

body > div {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

input {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="inputs">
  <button id='addinput'>Add input field</button>
  <input type="text" />
</div>
<div id="events"></div>
```

There is no problems if an event bubbles (for click or input events), but what is the best way to handle focus events in dynamically added inputs?

I don't have access to the code that adds the fields to the page. All I have is the ability to add JS code after the page is loaded.

Comment: What exactly is changing? Please post a [mcve]. It is right now very hard to make suggestions. Normally you would look at delegation - if so it is a [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: or [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896106/attach-event-to-dynamic-elements-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks, but it's seems like a duple of [this 
 question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22062602/htmlcollection-change-event-with-javascript)

Comment: If it is a dupe, feel free to delete the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1687296/6532549).

This is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/203198/6532549) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34896106/6532549) but those questions do not touch on events that do not bubble, like the `focus` event.

To implement event delegation on events that do not bubble, you will need to catch it during [event capturing phase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4616694/6532549). This can be done by using the [third argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#parameters) of the `.addEventListener` method:

```js
document.addEventListener('focus', function(event){ ... }, true);
/* OR */
document.addEventListener('focus', function(event){ ... }, { capture: true });
```

For the `focus` event specifically, you can also use the [`focusin` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusin_event). One of the differences between `focus` and `focusin` is that `focusin` bubbles:

```js
document.addEventListener('focusin', function(event){ ... });
```

Event delegation for `focus` event is discussed in [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focus_event#event_delegation).

```js
document.addEventListener('focus', (e) => console.log('focus', 'useCapture'), true);
document.addEventListener('focus', (e) => console.log('focus', '{ capture: true }'), { capture: true });
document.addEventListener('focusin', (e) => console.log('focusin'));
```

```html
<input>
```

Comment: Thank you! Catching events during capturing phase solves my problem!

Answer (score 0):

If an event bubbles you can catch it at the `document`:

```js
// emulate code on the page

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => {

  e.target.remove();

  document.querySelector('.container').innerHTML = `
    <input id="Text">
    <button class="btn">Auto click me</button>
    <div class="log"></div>
  `;

  const textbox = document.querySelector('#Text');
  textbox.focus();

  document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('.log').innerHTML += `<div>${textbox.value.trim()}</div>`;
    textbox.value = '';
  });
  
});

// your code, watch for inputs to change

document.addEventListener('input', e => {

  const button = document.querySelector('.btn');

  e.target.value.trim().length === 5 && setTimeout(() => button.click(), 100);

});
```

```html
<button>Add elements</button>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for You suggestion, but what if an event does't bubbles? Input focus, for example.